# Music with notes always going up

Tags: melody

Somehow the ["Vorrede" of "Also sprach Zarathustra"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Also_sprach_Zarathustra_(Strauss)) came to my mind (no wonder, it's sort of a pop-cultural meme) and I pondered that the (mostly!) ascending notes surely add to the symbolic.

A music piece wanting to always increase the pitch either has to [reuse the same note often](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/13127/most-monotone-music-piece), or blatantly [cheat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepard_tone)...or it will be relative short due to human ear pitch limitation. (A mere subset of a piece, say the outro of "Radar Love", obviously doesn't count here.) Do you know one?

Comment: I think [Music: Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/) site is more suitable for this question.

Comment: Are you asking for examples of what you're describing?

Comment: @Joachim: If you know one, shoot. :-)

Comment: It's just that that's a type of question that doesn't really suit the platform, similar to how identification questions are now off-topic, as well. If that's the intention of your question, you're better of asking it on a website like Reddit..

Comment: Doesn't qualify as an answer, but Pärt's *Cantus in Memoriam Benjamin Britten* consists entirely of *downward* seconds.

Comment: Far from music, but I only know this phenomenon is called [Shepard tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepard_tone), which is considered an auditory illusion.